# Fbx Export Smoke Simulation

Tags: smoke-simulation

can i export smoke simulation as .fbx file? I'm trying to export an animated mesh with smoke simulation all in .fbx file.

Thanks.

Comment: No, you can not.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541